# Kernel stops without reason

Tags: cuda

I have a problem with my first CUDA app. Basically it should generate N linear differential equations and solve them numerically using first order method. Variable `t` (time) iterates from 0 to `T` with step = `TAU` = 0.0001. If `T` is small enough (say 0.001), everything is ok, but if `T` == 0.1 or greater, it seems that kernel doesn't do anything. How do I examine this situation?

`N` - number of equations, `TAU` - time step, `TN` - number of threads per block, `T` - end time

Variable `r` doesn't do anything. I used it to verify if kernel does anything. So if `T` == 0.0001 then `r` == 283, but if `T` == 0.1, `r` == 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 4096
#define TAU 0.0001f
#define TN 2
#define T 0.1f
#define PI 3.141592f

__global__ void kern(float* v, float* m, float* r)
{
    *r = 283;
    __syncthreads();
    int tid = blockIdx.x*TN + threadIdx.x;

    for(float t = 0; t <= T; t += TAU)
    {
        float f = 0;
        __syncthreads();
        for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
            f += m[N*tid + k]*v[k];
        f *= TAU;
        f += v[tid];
        __syncthreads();
        v[tid] = f;
    }
}

int main()
{
    float* v = new float[N];
    float* m = new float[N*N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        v[i] = sin(2*PI*i/N); //setting initial conditions

    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; ++i)
        m[i] = cos(2*PI*i/(N*N)); //coefficients in right hand part of the equations

    // printing some of the values (total: 8 values) to compare with result
    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i += N*N / 8) printf("%f ", m[i]); printf("\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i += N / 8) printf("%f ", v[i]); printf("\n");

    float* cv;
    float* cm;
    float* cr;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&cv, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&cm, N*N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&cr, sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(cv, v, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(cm, m, N*N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 blocks(N / TN);
    dim3 threads(TN);

    time_t ts = time(0);
    printf("starting kernel\n");
    kern<<<blocks, threads>>>(cv, cm, cr);
    printf("kernel stopped\n");
    time_t ts_end = time(0);

    cudaMemcpy(v, cv, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    float r;
    cudaMemcpy(&r, cr, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i += N / 8) printf("%f ", v[i]); printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n", ts_end - ts);
    printf("result: %f\n", r);


    delete[] m;
    delete[] v;

    cudaFree(cv);
    cudaFree(cm);
    cudaFree(cr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "kernel stops"? Do you mean the printout from line 62?

Note that kernel launches are asynchronous - that is, line 61 does not wait for the kernel to complete. You should use "cudaDeviceSynchronize" after the kernel launch to wait for kernel completion. Note that cudaMemcpy will also synchronize on kernel launch.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that the kernel call was asynchronous. Added cudaDeviceSynchronize right after kernel call. After few seconds (which i guess shows that it actually does something) if fails with "unspecified launch failure". I'll inspect the code for memory corruption. By the way, will kernel fail if there is float overflow? Or it'll just ignore it and will continue with incorrect value?

Comment: Are you running your application on the same GPU that is also used by OS to display the UI? Note that these devices have a "watchdog timer" - long-running kernels are forcibly terminated to avoid choppy UI. You need a dedicated graphical adapter for long-running compute operations.

Comment: Note that I do see errors when running on the GPU that my monitor is connected to while running code on spare GPU does not yield any errors. I'm running it using cuda-memcheck now, takes awhile :)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense =) I do indeed get freeze for a while and then my app exits with error. I'm running it on GTS 250 and i don't have another card. How can this problem be solved? I can remove "for" loop from kernel code, by looping kernel call instead. So kernel will be started approx 10^3-10^4 times (with cudaDeviceSynchronize of course). Would this be ok (i mean is it ok to run kernel many times)?

Comment: Absolutely, you can run a kernel as many times as you want. You may want to check the barriers (__syncthreads) - to me it looks like you use excessive synchronization. Also you may be able to get rid of the inner loops by using parallel reductions.

Comment: Your block size should be a multiple of 32 - you will see the code executing much faster. But it really looks like the code can be sped up significantly by making it more parallel and by using shared memory, etc.

Comment: You are most certainly timing out. You are doing 4096 * 1000 inner loop iterations (all of your memory accesses) with only 2 threads per block. Your GPU is limited to 8 blocks / SM so you are only managing to execute 256 threads using 128 blocks. If you change your grid and block dimensions you should be able to increase this to >12K concurrent threads. At that point your 32-way divergence when reading m will be your primary performance problem. You can remove the __syncthreads and *r.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i understand the concept :)

Comment: (Still using your code to test our profiler) - note that the loop for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) can be made much faster if you use coalesced access (that is, each iteration accesses on the next row of the minstead of column with every thread reading next element). Note that I don't care about correctness in my testing so I don't know proper way of doing it - I'm just hacking the code.

Answer (score 1):

Always check for the return code when invoking the cuda api calls.

Most likely your program is never being run because of some api error.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Done. When T == 0.0001 it runs fine. When T == 0.1 programs fails on call CudaSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(v, cv, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); with message "unspecified launch failure". In both cases cudaGetLastError right after kernel call returns cudaSuccess, but when T == 0.1 it seems that kernel doesn't do anything.